# Errors in Stacked bar Graphs

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

Currently, I am receiving errors as I transfer my ggplot to plotly graph using the ggplotly command.

All my other graphs work perfectly except for the stacked bar graph. Is anyone having an issue here ? My code looks like this

```
 output$tvpn <- renderPlotly({
  mpolfinal4$Partner.Name= factor(mpolfinal4$Partner.Name,
                                levels=names(sort(table(mpolfinal4$Partner.Name),
                                                decreasing=FALSE)))




       tv =  ggplot(mpolfinal4, aes(x =Partner.Name, fill=Domain.Name)) + geom_bar(colour="black")+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))+ggtitle("Total Views by Partner Name, and Domain Name")

out = ggplotly(tv)
out
```

Comment: Hey Jon -- There may be an issue with the conversion. Stacked bars do work for most cases (https://plot.ly/ggplot2/geom_bar/#geom_bar-with-stacked-traces) but you might've uncovered an issue that is particular to your dataset. Could you provide a simple, reproducible example that includes a simplified representative dataframe? Thx!

Comment: Hey Chris, I did sedt you an email with my datasets and code a couple weeks back but have not heard back from you.

Let me know if you need any more info?

-Justin